# Using a decorator inside the class and call the object

Tags: python, oop, python-decorators

I have a class with a function called `decorator_func` and another function called `name_me`. How do I decorate the `name_me` function with the other function from the class?

Here is what I tried so far:

```html
class Test :
    
    def decorator_func(fun):
        def disp_fun(name):
            return ("hello there ,") + fun(name)
        return disp_fun
@decorator_func
def name_me(name):
      return name
    
print name_me("abhi")

obj = Test()
obj.decorator_func()
```

[The description of the code is mentioned in the image given below .
Anaconda jyupiter lab is used to execute the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgKdl.png)

How to Remove this error?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is, that you decorate the `name_me` function with a method from the `Test` class.

You can either move the `decorator_func` from the `Test` class, then your code would look like this:

```
def decorator_func(fun):
    def disp_fun(name):
        return ("hello there, ") + fun(name)
    return disp_fun

@decorator_func
def name_me(name):
  return name

print name_me("abhi")
```

Our you create an instance of the `Test` class and decorate the `name_me` function with the method of the instance, like this:

```
class Test :
    def decorator_func(self, fun):
        def disp_fun(name):
            return ("hello there, ") + fun(name)
        return disp_fun

# Create a instance of the Test class
obj = Test()

@obj.decorator_func
def name_me(name):
    return name

print name_me("abhi")
```